# RecyclerView refreshes list values and causes Index out of bounds exception

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new and naive to android development so I apologize if this a very basic question.

In our current application, I have a recyclerview which renders a checkbox which contains a list of categories. Within each category, there are several other sub categories for example

- Food (One of the Categories)

  - Veggies
  - Poultry
  - Meat
  - so on and so forth let's say 10 such sub-categories

My concern is initially on page load, the subcategory has 10 items. When the user scrolls in a way that only 5 items are visible on the UI and then selects the last value in sub category, I see an index out of bounds exception.

Root cause is that within the onBindView method, the sub category arraylist got refreshed by recyclerview to hold only 5 items and when I try to get(10th) position from that arraylist, I run into out of bounds exception.
I have spent 3 days searching this on the web but I have no idea how to stop my arraylist from getting refreshed such that it does not change its value if some of the categories are not visible on the UI when a user scrolls.
Request your help so that I can bring a peaceful end to 2020.

Below is my onbindview snippet

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    subCategoryModel = arrayList_sub_categories.get(position);

    holder.catName.setText(subCategoryModel.getsSubCatName());

    holder.catName.setChecked(arrayList_sub_categories.get(position).getSelected());

    holder.catName.setTag(position);

    String strSubCategory = SharedPrefrence_Seller.getFixr_shop_Subcategoryid();

    holder.catName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //This is where I try to get the selected tag which gives me the index 10th if I selected the last sub category
            Integer pos = (Integer) holder.catName.getTag();
            //Below line gives an index out of bounds because my arrayList_sub_categories got refreshed to have only 5 values which are visible on the UI and I am trying to get the 10th value
            subCategoryModel = arrayList_sub_categories.get(pos);
            req = split;
            if(!(subCategoryModel==null)) {
                //Do bunch of stuff here
            }
```

I am adding more code snippets to tell you about the list in question arrayList_sub_categories is set via API callout in another class via the below snippet

```
private void func_fetch_CategoryAPI(final String sCategoryNAme, final String stype) {

        requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(ServiceSelctionActivity.this).getRequestQueue();
        //if everything is fine
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Urls.URL_SALES_FETCH_CATEGORY_ITEMS,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            //converting response to json object and all this is not relevant to this question
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            String str = obj.getString("data");
                            arrayListCatItem.clear();
                            arrayListsubCatItem.clear();
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(str);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsoObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Model_Item_Category model_item_category = new Model_Item_Category();
                                hashMapListChooseCat = new HashMap<>();
                                hashMapListChooseCatStatus = new HashMap<>();
                                model_item_category.setCatId(jsoObject.getString("id"));
                                model_item_category.setPosition_key(jsoObject.getString("position_key"));
                                model_item_category.setCatName(jsoObject.getString("cat_name"));
                                model_item_category.setCatIconName(jsoObject.getString("image_url"));
                                model_item_category.setSub_cat_status(jsoObject.getString("sub_cat_status"));
//finally
                                model_item_category.setCheckLevel(strcheck_level);
                                strSelectedService = SharedPrefrence_Seller.getFixr_shop_categoryid();
                                arrayListCatItem.add(model_item_category);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //Here is where adapter_category is set which is a custom class object that includes the list model_item_category in question
                    rvSelectService.setAdapter(adapter_category);
                    adapter_category.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
```

Definition of adapter_category is

```
public Adapter_Category(Context activity, List<Model_Item_Category> subCategoryList, HashMap<String, String> hashMapListChooseCat,
                            HashMap<String, String> hashMapListChooseCatStatus, TextView tvService)
```

Comment: Try change `Integer pos = (Integer) holder.catName.getTag();` to `Integer pos = (Integer) view.getTag();`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix the problem but you can give it a shot. In your getItemCount() method, did you accidently minus 1? If so remove that and just include the size of the arrayList_sub_categories.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList_sub_categories.size();
}
```